# best way to check nameservers of a domain name

Tags: dns, nameservers

What is the best way to check nameservers of a domain?

I am trying :
`dig @8.8.8.8 +short bpo.in`

However this page shows that bpo.in has nameservers : https://who.is/dns/bpo.in

Answer (score 0):

Using query type NS:

```
dig ns <your domain>
```

[Dig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)